# How to access Google Classroom without API?

Tags: node.js, api, google-classroom

I'd like to automatize some processes that are not yet available through API(Google Classroom), like posting comments on announcements, seeing private comments on my work and so on. I have trouble accessing my account. I'd like the app to be able to run on a server. I'm currently working with node.js, but if there is an easier approach I'll gladly accept it (free if it's possible). Can you give me an example of how it's done because currently, I am struggling to find every button that needs to be clicked on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no methods right now to accomplish that. You can leave a [feature request on Google Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing what methods you would like to use. Google engineers will study your case and, if applicable, they will develop the requested methods.

Comment: Considering the situation that won't happen soon, and after I won't use google classroom. I tried something with express and got stuck with the security problems, the google won't allow me to automate the process of logging into my account. So I wanted to ask is there any way that I can legally avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) with your language of choice (Javascript in this case) to automate the browser clicks.

This is however, not the best of ideas... To make Selenium log into your account you will need to hardcode your password somewhere.

Google services use Oauth for authentication, take a look at the [Classroom API Getting-started](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/get-started) for instructions on how to work with Google Classroom API.